# Example of level set method

Tags: finite-element

I am looking for easily to understand example of level set method used to track phases interfaces. I would like to solve it using FEM because my solution is based on the FEM solution of second Fick law. Initialization step is straight forward - it just distance of each node from the interface. But I have problem with second step - solution of the interface velocity equation:

$$ \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial t}+F\left| \nabla \phi  \right|=0 $$

If I understand correctly I need a weak formulation of that differential equation, where F is linear velocity of the interface. Solution will give me a new position of the interface. Is it correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Yes, $\phi=0$ always locates the interface even at later times. See below for more details:

---

A level set function, $\phi(x,y,t)$, in two dimensions, describes a function whose zero-level set describes your interface. To be precise, a level-set function $\phi$ divides your domain $\Omega$ into three disjoint subdomains:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcr}
\Omega^- &:(x,y,t) \:&|\: & \phi(x,y,t) < 0 \\
\Gamma   &:(x,y,t) \:&|\: & \phi(x,y,t) = 0 \\
\Omega^+ &:(x,y,t) \:&|\: & \phi(x,y,t) > 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Assuming that $\phi(x,y,t) = 0$ **always** denotes the interface $\Gamma$, it is clear that the the interface must satisfy:
$$
\frac{D \phi}{D t} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + \mathbf{V} \cdot \nabla \phi = 0
$$

Furthermore, since $\phi(x,y,t) = 0$ on $ \Gamma$, this equation may be written to only involve the velocity in the **normal** direction 
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + v_n \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n} = 0
$$
However, since $\Gamma$ is a level-set, we have the following relation for the unit normal:
$$
\hat{\mathbf{n}} = \frac{\nabla \phi}{\left|\nabla \phi\right|}
$$
Thus, the evolution equation simplifies to:
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + v_n \left|\nabla \phi\right| = 0
$$

This is your version of the equation with $F = v_n$. It is sometimes referred to as **motion in the normal direction**.

To summarize, the zero level-set of $\phi(x,y,t)$ always locates the interface when you solve the level-set equation (either in its original form or normal motion form). I suggest you consult the following two standard texts for more details and actual implementation:

[Sethian's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521645573)

[Osher & Fedkiw's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387954821)

The first one includes a chapter on weak formulation and FEM methods for the solution whereas the second is mainly involved with FDM methods.

Answer (score 5):

For the level set equation, $\phi=0$ denotes your interface and which you initialize suitably. Then based on your convection equation, you move $\phi$ (depends on how you want to solve it, if using FEM, then you need the weak formulation etc.) and again find  $\phi=0$ which would give you the location of your convected interface. However, the level set function gets smeared out after some iterations. Hence, you may have to re-initialize it.

I find this tutorial to be relatively easier to understand: http://persson.berkeley.edu/pub/persson05levelset.pdf Hope it helps.

For the FEM framework, Chapter 5 of this [thesis](http://www.nada.kth.se/utbildning/grukth/exjobb/rapportlistor/2006/rapporter06/lindbo_dag_06153.pdf) should be helpful.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question. @KrzysztofBzowski is asking how to evolve the level set equation in time within an FEM framework, whereas the tutorial only covers finite difference discretizations.

Comment: @Ben: I thought the question was more focussed on the way LSM works. I have included a reference for FEM formulation of LSM.